# Why aren't my calculations performing in my function that has been called within another function?

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner in Python and still have lots to learn. That being said I will try to explain my problem as best as possible. I am currently designing a program that asks you a question and prompts you for an answer. Based off that answer it will ask another question and input then calculate or not calculate your paycheck before taxes (it depends on your answers). I know none of it is related but it's a class projects. **In my opinion** my code is working nearly perfect except the fact it is not doing the one calculation I am asking it to do. I need to multiply variables *hours* and *rate* to get the final total for the users paycheck. Below is my code. I have tried everything I know and searched but can't seem to find an answer.

```
def get_question():
    question1 = input('Do you want to hear a joke?: (Y/N) ')
    catJoke = 'What do you call a pile of cats? A meowtain!'
    catJoke2 = "Why was the cat afraid of the tree? Because of it's bark!"
    if question1 == 'Y':
        print(catJoke)
        print('')
    elif question1 == 'y':
        print(catJoke)
        print('')
    elif question1 == 'N' or question1 == 'n':
        print('Too bad!')
        print(catJoke2)
        print('')

def showIntro():
    rate = 0.00
    hours = 0.00
    intro = input('Hello, did you like your joke? (Y/N): ')
    if intro == 'Y' or intro == 'y':
        print('Thank you! Because you liked my joke I will help you calculate your 
        paycheck!')
        get_rate()
        get_hours()
        get_paycheck(rate , hours)

    if intro == 'N' or intro == 'n':
        print('Goodbye!')
        print('')

def get_rate():
    rate = float(input('Enter hourly rate:$ '))
    return rate

def get_hours():
    hours = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
        if hours >= 41:
            print('Your base hours including overtime is: '+ str(hours))
        if hours <= 40:
            print('Your hours entered were: ' +str(hours))
        return hours

def get_paycheck(rate , hours):
    paycheck = rate * hours
    end = ''
    if hours >= 41:
        print('Your weekly paycheck with overtime and before taxes is:$' , (rate * hours) * 
               1.5)
        print(end)
    elif hours <=40:
        print('Your weekly paycheck before taxes is:$' , rate * hours)
        print(end)
    return rate , hours

while True:
        get_question()
        showIntro()
```

Comment: `get_rate()` and `get_hours()` all return some value. You need to store them in variables like `rate = get_rate()` and `hours = get_hours()` when you call them in the `showIntro()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that caused the issue:

```
def showIntro():
    rate = 0.00
    hours = 0.00
    intro = input('Hello, did you like your joke? (Y/N): ')
    if intro == 'Y' or intro == 'y':
        print('Thank you! Because you liked my joke I will help you calculate your 
        paycheck!')
        get_rate()
        get_hours()
        get_paycheck(rate , hours)
```

You see, you set `rate` and `hour` to `0`, and when you call the functions, they do not overwrite the variables, they only return values. So, you either need to put the functions into the brackets, or assign the values into the variables:

```
def showIntro():
    intro = input('Hello, did you like your joke? (Y/N): ')
    if intro == 'Y' or intro == 'y':
        print('Thank you! Because you liked my joke I will help you calculate your paycheck!')
        get_paycheck(get_rate() , get_hours())
```

*note: You have an indentation error at `get_hours()`.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it could be one of a few things. Your function get_paycheck is returning the rate and the hour separately, not multiplied. If that is not the purpose, then I also see that in your print command, you separated the parts by commas and in Python, it is a + to add strings in a print command. If it is getting an error than it may be due to the order that you define the functions.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm new to python too and I love these mini programs!**

```
def show_intro():
# your issue was here rate = 0.00
# your issue was here hours = 0.00
intro = input('Hello, did you like your joke? (Y/N): ')
if intro == 'Y' or intro == 'y':
    print('Thank you! Because you liked my joke I will help you calculate your paycheck!')
    rate = get_rate()
    hours = get_hours()
    get_paycheck(rate, hours)

if intro == 'N' or intro == 'n':
    print('Goodbye!')
    print('')
```

You had to define the functions so that they can be used as arguments in get_paycheck()

Hope this helps!